# Could not find a part of the path (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

Hi I keep getting this error:

```
Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Websites\site_sitecore\Website\Template\claim.htm'.
```

The code I'm using is:

```
message.BodyFileName = "/Template/claim.htm";
```

Basically trying to send an email template via email but I can't get it to find the path. If I use a external link with that file it denies access to it but can't work out how to get the correct path to work internally, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried searching through Windows Explorer for that file? Does it actually exist in that location?

Comment: Note that you are specifying the path from the root. You might want to debug the code and crosscheck the path with the actual path...!!

Comment: Hello David. When posting code, select the code and press Ctrl+K or alternatively click the **Code Sample** button in the panel. :)

Comment: The files hosted on an external server, also unsure wy it's giving it a D path

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray yeah I'm unsure of the full path as I can't work out how you find this on a site hosted within sitecore?

Comment: fund solution now, was something silly, missed a folder! Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Use Server.MapPath('~/Template/claim.htm'). Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

try `message.BodyFileName = "Template/claim.htm";`

Comment: can you give me the actual path of the file ?!